# Android IntentFilter for Every New Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

Is it possible to register a global broadcast receiver that gets notified every time a new activity is started (either by startActivity, startActivityForResult, etc)? What would the IntentFilter be?

EDIT: Just to clarify, I don't mean across apps I mean within my own app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could potentially create your own partial subclass of `Activity` where it overrides `onCreate()`, `onStart()`, etc and manually calls a static/singleton instance of your global receiver as appropriate. After that, just derive your own activities' implementations from that subclass.

However, I'm assuming the reason you want to do this is that the "receiver" actually contains or otherwise represents some globally available state or resource - if you can find a way to implement your application without having any global state (and just passing it along as payload for an activity call, for instance), that would be best.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to do that.